# Cannot get any scalajs-bundler samples to work

Tags: scalajs-bundler

If I download a clone of the [scalajs-bundler](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler) project and navigate to any of the sbt-test projects I cannot get any of them to work - for example the facade project.

When I enter the sbt command I get the following error:

> [error] java.lang.RuntimeException: 'plugin.version' environment variable not set

Full stack trace is:

[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: 'plugin.version' environment variable is not set
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
[error]     at $0813db5cafe4ec2bbe2c$.$anonfun$$sbtdef$1(/home/des/workspace/scalajs-bundler-master/sbt-scalajs-bundler/src/sbt-test/sbt-scalajs-bundler/facade/project/plugins.sbt:3)
[error]     at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:127)
[error]     at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse$(MapLike.scala:125)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
[error]     at $0813db5cafe4ec2bbe2c$.$sbtdef(/home/des/workspace/scalajs-bundler-master/sbt-scalajs-bundler/src/sbt-test/sbt-scalajs-bundler/facade/project/plugins.sbt:3)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error]     at sbt.compiler.Eval$.getValue(Eval.scala:578)
[error]     at sbt.compiler.Eval.$anonfun$eval$1(Eval.scala:129)
[error]     at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.$anonfun$evaluateDslEntry$1(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:249)
[error]     at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$6(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:172)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:294)
[error]     at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$4(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:172)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:1137)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$discoverProjects$2(Load.scala:1144)
[error]     at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:127)
[error]     at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse$(MapLike.scala:125)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:1143)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$discoverProjects$4(Load.scala:1151)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:1151)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:1165)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:862)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:937)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:726)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$11(Load.scala:729)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:729)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:688)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:484)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:176)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:241)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:546)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:562)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:492)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:471)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:251)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:251)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.buildPluginDefinition(Load.scala:1312)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:1242)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:1225)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$2(Load.scala:694)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:694)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:688)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:484)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:176)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:241)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:546)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:562)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:492)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:471)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:251)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:251)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:69)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:829)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:829)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:800)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] 'plugin.version' environment variable is not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests rely on sbt-scripted to be executed. See the instructions in the [contributing file](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#run-the-tests).